# React-router 6 and .Net spa: exclude /api endpoints

Tags: reactjs, .net, react-router

i have a .Net spa with react-router. I did need react-router as i have some redirects (ie: after msal authentication, or some authorized routes ) to manage. Problem is, now i'm unable to serve both BE and FE on the same port, as every call to `[URL:PORT]/api/myendpoint` are now intercepted by react-router.

Is there a way to exclude certain paths from react-router management? For some constrains, i do need a single container to manage the app.

Thank you.